# SQL Server Stored Procedure self-profiled for execution time?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, execution-time, sql-server-profiler

I need to find and store in a table the execution time of a procedure everytime it is being executed.

Is there a way I can do it **from within the procedure**? Lets say use a query to find  its execution time and write it inside a table?

Any other better methods to record the execution times of the procedure other than use Profiler and filter thousand of thousands of records?

Thank you

Comment: `filter thousand of thousands of records` - setup appropriate filter **before** starting your trace.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use two parameters and initialize one at the start of the procedure and the next at the end of the procedure.

```
create procedure myproc as
begin
    declare @start_time datetime = getdate()

    (rest of procedure code)

    declare @end_time datetime = getdate()
end
```

Right before exiting the procedure you can insert these values into a logging table.

```
INSERT INTO Proc_Exec_Log (procedure_name, start_time, end_time) 
VALUES ('myproc', @start_time, @end_time);
```